# Спряжения глаголов

Tags: спряжение

У глаголов есть спряжения. 1-е и 2-е. Например, глагол "любить" 2-го спряжения. Были ли учёные-лингвисты, которые меняли местами спряжения в своих учебниках? Например, Виноградов...   И если можно, ссылочку..
Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Такой факт мне неизвестен. Вроде бы все излагают одинаково. Современные спряжения - итог развития древних спряжений в старославянском, уже тогда было 2 спряжения. Но трудностей со спряжениями хватает:исключения, разноспрягаемые, недостаточные глаголы,с излишней парадигмой. Всё это-результат развития языка, изменения классов глагола, ведь спряжение зависит от основы глагола наст. вр. определённого класса, классы исчезали, спряжения перемешались.

Вот здесь есть интересные сведения:

http://kvatross.ru/parts-of-the-speech/779.html

http://orthowiki.kalan.cc/wiki/

Comment: Поправочка: не в старославянском, а в древнерусском...

Comment: Разницы нет, система глаголов одинакова - что в древнерусском, что в старославянском.Грамматика Смотрицкого выпущена на древнецерковнославянском,т.е. старославянском, историческая грамматика рассматривает влияние ВСЕХ процессов древнего языка.Для лингвистики значение старославянского языка определяется прежде всего его древностью, благодаря чему он ближе всех других славянских языков стоит к гипотетическому праславянскому языку.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что ученые лингвисты вряд ли уполномочены назначать спряжение или менять его. Они, скорее, наблюдают за языковыми процессами, объясняют и делают выводы, систематизируют материал. Например, в речи встречаются две формы: он мучит и мучает. Форму "мучит" (нейтральный стиль) относят к глаголу 2-ого спряжения "мучить", а форму "мучает" (разговорный стиль) - к глаголу 1-ого спряжения "мучать".

Интересны в этом смысле отыменные глаголы "опротиветь" и "выздороветь". Здесь один и тот же глагол имеет две формы (нейтральную и чисто разговорную): опротивеет, выздоровеет - опротивит, выздоровит, например:    "Конечно, нет в нем этого ума, что гений для иных, а для иных чума, который скор, блестящ и скоро опротивит (Грибоедов).